# TFS | Automated Test Run | Aborted | Test results modified by other user/session

Tags: tfsbuild

I am running an automated test case through MTM while in the code behind, I am updating the test results with some more fields for the running test run and saving it.
Though, am getting an error as final state of MTM test run is "Aborted".
I get following error -

Unexpected Error occurred. Aborting run: Test results have been modified by another user or session. You must reload the test run and update the test results again.

Code -

> ITestRun testRun = project.TestRuns.Find(testRunID);
>   ITestCaseResult result = testRun.QueryResults()[0];
>   result.FailureTypeId = (int)FailureType.NewIssue;
>   result.ResolutionStateId = 2;
>   result.Save();
>   testRun.Save();
>   testRun.Refresh();

Comment: When you run the code above, the test run you get from testRunID isn't finished in MTM? If so, you need to wait the test Run finishes and then run these code above to update test result.

Comment: The test run executes a background code which includes the above code as well. So Yes, the testRunID isn't finished in MTM. I need to update the results in underlying code while the test run is still executing.

Comment: Why do you want to do so, this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not allowed to do so.

If you want to edit the test results, you need to wait the test run finishes and test results have generated already, then you could use the API code to change it.